# Use the font awesome library with Ratchet

Tags: cordova, font-awesome, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

I am building an app with ratchet and am trying to use the font awesome library but nothing seems to work. I have tried:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

but nothing seems to work.

What I have tried is downloading the font awesome files and placing them inside my project folder
I then try to call upon an icon as such:

```
<div class="card">
            <ul class="table-view">
                <li class="table-view-cell media">
                    <a class="navigate-right">
                        <span class="media-object pull-left"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></span>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            Reserve a Table
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This will render properly on google chrome in the emulation mode. Yet when I upload this to phonegap and use it on my phone the icon does not show up anymore.

Any ideas? I am using Phonegap to compile my code.

Thanks

Comment: That will load a stylesheet, but you haven't given enough information to diagnose a problem. Post some code

Comment: I added some code. Am I calling it correctly? Even if I dont put it in a span tag and just call it on its own it still wont show up on my phone but will render fine on the emulation on google chrome

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/5voo97w1/
You have confirmed that your css is applied correctly. If this is on a secondary page that gets navigated to, the css you are importing won't be applied to the page. Push.js loads the content via ajax and applies it to your existing DOM so the head styles/scripts are lost. If this content is on your app's landing page, check to make sure that your stylesheet isn't getting lost in the build process. Create your project with from the command line with `cordova create platforms ios` and take a look at the `platforms` folder for the generated project